# Permissions issue with Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have an issue with database permissions.

I have the following permission:

```
 "products_invisible": {
          "$pid": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": 
                true,//"auth != null && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true)",
            ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0",
        },
        ".read": true,
    }

 "products_visible": {
          "$pid": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": 
                true,//"auth != null && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true)",
            ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0",
        },
        ".read": true,
    }

 "products": {
          "$pid": {
            ".read": true,
            ".write": 
                true,//"auth != null && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true)",
            ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0",
        },
        ".read": true,
    }
```

I am trying to push some data:

```
            var productData = {
                <some data>                
            };

            // Get a key for a new Post.
            var newProductKey = firebase.database().ref().child('products').push().key;
            var updates = {};

            updates['/products/' + newProductKey] = productData;//all products

            //we also need to add product to other db tables
            if(!vm.newProduct.visibility) {
                updates['/products_invisible/' + newProductKey] = productData;
            }
            //visible products table
            else if(vm.newProduct.visibility) {
                updates['/products_visible/' + newProductKey] = productData;

             }

            //update
            firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

However, I see the following errors, not sure why. Am I missing something here ?

```
firebase.js:281 FIREBASE WARNING: update at / failed: permission_denied L @ firebase.js:281(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:454(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:386g.wd @ firebase.js:387qg.wd @ firebase.js:377(anonymous function) @ firebase.js:375cg @ firebase.js:359La.onmessage @ firebase.js:358
firebase.js:458 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied(…)
```

Comment: You're updating `/products`, which you don't seem to have permission to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your snippet:

1. You're updating `/products`, which you don't seem to have permission to.
2. You validate that `/products_visible/quantity` is greater than 0, which I doubt you wanted to do. More likely you want each product to have a quantity, which you do with:

   ```
   "products_visible": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true,//"auth != null && (root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('user').child('admin').val() == true)",
     "$productid": {
       ".validate": "newData.child('quantity').val() >= 0"
     }
   },
   ```

Problem 1 might be just forgetting to add it to the question, but #2 is definitely a problem.